# escaping html markup

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a html table using javascript on the fly and I want to add a cell that may contain html markup.  I do not want that markup interpreted but simply displayed.

```
  LogHTML += "<tr><td>" + data + "</td></tr>";
```

How can I do that?  Is there some function or html markup that will accomplish that?

I tried pre but then I get extra spaces.

Comment: Every major JS library has the code to do that, don't re-invent the wheel.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I escape html special chars in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234773/can-i-escape-html-special-chars-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LogHTML += "<tr><td>"+data.replace(/</g,"&lt;")+"</td></tr>";
```

That's all you need.

Comment: Thanks, See article referenced above for a function to handle this and other cases.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to use DOM instead of `innerHTML` and to create text node for `data`.

But you can try [this](http://phpjs.org/functions/htmlentities:425) as a quick solution or

```
function htmlentities(s){
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    var text = document.createTextNode(s);
    div.appendChild(text);
    return div.innerHTML;
}
```