# can't get unicode character to display properly - Javascript and HTML

Tags: javascript, unicode

I'd like to put a unicode up arrow in an html input button that is being generated in Javascript.

These are the codes for the up arrow from unicode-table.com:
Unicode number: U+2191
HTML-code: & #8593; (space between the & and # so you can see the code and not the arrow)

I do have
    `<charset="utf-8" />`
in my head tag in the html file.

I've tried every variation of those two codes I can think of within the <> below and all I get in the browser is the text of the codes I've tried.

Here's the line of code:

```
upButton.setAttribute("value", "<up arrow code here>");
```

Comment: If stuff is being treated as HTML, etc, use the code formatting, that's what it's there for.

Comment: not sure what you mean by that @Alex. It seems if I create the button in the html file it works fine, but create th button in Javascript and it will not.  For my purposes I need to create it in Javascript, however.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert Unicode character into JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13093126/insert-unicode-character-into-javascript)

Comment: Try this: `'\u{2191}'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this string instead of an html escape character (this is a JavaScript string after all, not an html text node) `\u2191'`

Comment: or maybe `'\x8593'`but I kind of doubt it.

Comment: Thank you - what worked was actually `"\u2191"` your answer got me the closest and trial and error got me the rest of the way.

Comment: @ThorSummoner No, the `\x` prefix is used for the so-called [hexadecimal escape sequences](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes#hexadecimal) in JavaScript, and those only accept two digits (not four). So you have to use the [Unicode escape sequence](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes#unicode) which accepts four digits, as in your post.

Answer (score 2):

To [escape any symbol in JavaScript](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes), use this tool: http://mothereff.in/js-escapes#1%E2%86%91 For your example, `'↑'` becomes `'\u2191'`.

To escape any symbol in HTML, use this tool: http://mothereff.in/html-entities#%E2%86%91 For your example, `↑` becomes `&#x2191;` or `&uarr;`.

Comment: Awesome, buddy!

Answer (score 0):

Try using this in your html:    `&uparrow;`