# Unicode Character 'BULLET' in Titanium App

Tags: javascript, android, unicode, titanium, titanium-mobile

I have a problem with the BULLET character in my Android App developed with Titanium.

I have this part of code:

```
    function getFormattedPizza()
{
    var text = win.crust + ' pizza with:\n';
    if (win.toppings.length == 0)
    {
        text += '&bull; Plain (cheese pizza)\n';
    }
    else
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < win.toppings.length; i++)
        {
            text += '&bull; ' + win.toppings[i] + '\n';
        }
    }
    return text;
}
```

and in my app I see the string *&bull ; Plain (cheese pizza)*, not an unordered list.

In that way I can show a dots list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of `&bull` you can use the `'\u2022'+'Plain (cheese pizza)'`, `\u2022` is the unicode for bullet.

Samlple code :

```
var lbl = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text : '\u2022'+' HELLO'
});
win.add(lbl);
```

For more unicodes you can check this [Link](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b.htm), or refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13093126/insert-unicode-character-into-javascript).

Hope this will help you. :)

Comment: @sharkbait, `&bull;` is an HTML escape for “•”. Otherwise, e.g. in a JavaScript string, it is just six Ascii characters (though such a string can be processed so that it will be parsed as HTML, but that’s a different thing). In JavaScript, use the `\u02022` escape or the character “•” (if the character encoding of the file containing it has been properly declared, as it should be anyway).