# find regexp in document. getelementbyid

Tags: javascript, regex

I am new to reg exp I have searched lot about pattern to find the circle brackets in the string value finally i found. But this was not working when i am getting the value from DIV

Here is the javascript code

```
function myText(){   
 var inputString = document.getElementById("text").innerHTML;
 var result = inputString.match(/\(+/g);
 alert(result);
 }
 myText();
```

HTML code

```
<div  id="text">
 welcome to (MotherLand)
</div>
```

I tried with removing .value from the inputString

I am getting the result as **null** in alert. I tried with removing .value from the inputString

Iam getting the error in console window 
**Cannot read property 'match' of undefined**

I am getting the result as null in alert

I want only the circle brackets not inside the value.

The output should be  **(**

Kindly explain me what I am doing wrong.

fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/tvxmrLgv/3/)

Thanks
Mahadevan

Comment: `innerHTML.value` will be `undefined`. Try `getElementById('text').textContent`

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to get the string with in the `()`, then you could use the following regex Pattern

http://jsfiddle.net/12auwf1s/

`var inputString = document.getElementById("text").innerHTML`

`var result = inputString.match(/\(([^)]+)\)/);`

`//result[0] contains (Motherland)`

`//result[1] contains Motherland`

Comment: Hi,

thanks for the output but i want only the circle brackets not inside the value.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the things I see wrong:

1. You need to get the value like this.

   ```
   var inputString = document.getElementById("text").innerHTML;
   ```
2. The expression you want to find the text between "circle brackets" is:

   ```
   var result = inputString.match(/\(([^\)]+)\)/);

   \(      // Match open parenthesis
   (       // Start a capture group
   [^\)]+  // Match any character except a close parenthesis, repeating.
   )       // End capture group
   \)      // Match close parenthesis
   ```

   `result` will be an array. The first position will be the entire match and subsequent positions in the array will be any capture groups from your expression. So to get the text from between the parenthesis you would access `result[1]`.
3. I had trouble duplicating it in your jsFiddle because of the arabic characters. You may have to find the actual unicode values of those characters and use them in your regular expression. [Insert Unicode character into JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13093126/insert-unicode-character-into-javascript)

Here's a demo without the arabic characters: http://jsfiddle.net/tvxmrLgv/7/

Comment: Hi,

thanks for the output but i want only the circle brackets not inside the value.

Comment: Then simply move the capture group parenthesis outside of the `\(` and `\)`. Like this: `var result = inputString.match(/(\([^\)]+\))/);`. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tvxmrLgv/10/. Now it includes the parenthesis in the match.

Comment: thank you so much for the reply. I don't want the text inside the bracket. I want only the open parenthesis not the close parenthesis.

Comment: Why would you use a regular expression to match a single open parenthesis? That's a really strange requirement, but here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/tvxmrLgv/11/