# Adding icons to pseudo elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, unicode

I'm trying to add icons to my navigation (which dynamically changes) via JavaScript.

Here is my code (or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/venkatraj/o36xysg6/2/)):

```js
var icon = document.querySelector('#icon');
icon.setAttribute('data-icon', '&#x086;');
```

```css
#icon:after {
  content: attr(data-icon);
}
```

```html
<div id="icon" data-icon="">
  Icon
</div>
```

But it is not working, why? When tried to edit `data-icon` attribute manually, icon appears. Otherwise just unicode of icon.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert Unicode character into JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13093126/insert-unicode-character-into-javascript)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HTML entities don't have any meaning in CSS. If you want to follow that path you need to decode it first:

```js
var icon = document.querySelector('#icon');
var tmp = document.createElement("span");
tmp.innerHTML = '&#x86;';
icon.setAttribute('data-icon', tmp.innerText);
```

```css
#icon:after {
  content: attr(data-icon);
}
```

```html
<div id="icon" data-icon="">
  Icon
</div>
```

... or, alternatively, just type character as-is (as long as your application is written in UTF-8):

```js
var icon = document.querySelector('#icon');
icon.setAttribute('data-icon', '†');
```

```css
#icon:after {
  content: attr(data-icon);
}
```

```html
<div id="icon" data-icon="">
  Icon
</div>
```

Last but not least, CSS also accepts escape sequences but you need to use the [appropriate syntax](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes). This approach, however, does not seem to work for your specific character:

```js
var icon = document.querySelector('#icon');
// Brackets added for visibility, not part of the syntax
icon.setAttribute('data-icon', '(\u0086)(\u2020)');
```

```css
#icon:after {
  content: attr(data-icon);
}
```

```html
<div id="icon" data-icon="">
  Icon
</div>
```

I presume it's related to the fact that [U+2020 'DAGGER'](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2020/index.htm) (that works fine) is a [regular character](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Po/index.htm) but the one you're using [U+0086 'START OF SELECTED AREA'](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0086/index.htm) (which doesn't show) is a [control character](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Cc/index.htm). As you mention in a follow-up comment, you're using FontAwesome and such libraries provide custom fonts that map certain code points to display icons (though they normally use [private areas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas) to avoid conflicts).

Comment: Thanks Alvaro! That solved the issue. Most liked part in your answer is that the answer itself converts entities into unicode.
FYI: It comes from FontAwesome.

Comment: @venkatraj I eventually figured out why I was having issues with `U+0086`. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

That is obviously because `setAttribute` is escaping your special characters...and anyway you need to use CSS encoded icons and not an HTML entity. use [this convertor](http://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/):

`&#x086;` → `\0086`

I would suggest working with *meaningful* names instead of hard-coded writing the icon's code into an attribute.

### For example:

```
var icon = document.querySelector('#icon');
icon.setAttribute('data-icon', 'icon-heart');

[data-icon=icon-heart]{
    content:'\2764';
}
```

(better that all your icons elements will have a shared class which shared properties)

Comment: Thanks for the converter link.

Answer (score 1):

## Encoding minefield

See [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393462/placing-unicode-character-in-css-content-value/10393517#10393517) for more details.

**Answer updated (see comments and [edits](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44754861/revisions)).**

In short, I recommend using the character instead of any method of encoding it.  It will be vital in this case that your HTML files are correctly encoded and that they properly inform browsers what the encoding is.

```js
var js = document.querySelectorAll( ".js" );
js[ 0 ].setAttribute( "data-icon", "\u0086" );
js[ 1 ].setAttribute( "data-icon", "†" );
```

```css
.css:after {
    content: "\86";
    color: red;
}
.css.char:after {
    content: "†";
    color: blue;
}
.data:after {
    content: attr( data-icon );
}
.js:after {
    content: attr( data-icon );
}
.red:after {
    color: red;
}
.blue:after {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="css">hard coded css content</div>
<div class="css char">hard coded css content char</div>
<br>
<div class="data red" data-icon="&#x086;">hard coded data-icon</div>
<div class="data blue" data-icon="†">hard coded data-icon char</div>
<br>
<div class="js red">data-icon by js</div>
<div class="js blue">data-icon by js char</div>
```

Comment: This should explain it: [Insert Unicode character into JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13093126/insert-unicode-character-into-javascript)

Comment: I run the code snippet but no icon is displayed after text "Icon", it's just blank. Is that expected behavior?

Comment: @shaochuancs - In what browser do you not see the icon? I am using Google's Chrome, and it's all good.

Comment: @FredGandt I'm using Chrome Version 59.0.3071.109 on Mac

Comment: Also tested on Firefox, Safari and Opera, no luck :( It seems more like a Mac issue...

Comment: @shaochuancs - I'm not sure why this isn't working for you, and for me, the timing of the need to debug the problem couldn't be worse. I will attempt to figure it out in a couple of hours, but **have** to log off now. Sorry. I'll be back though. Maybe someone else will assist while I'm away.

Comment: Thanks @FredGandt

Comment: It doesn't work here either (Firefox/54.0 x64 on Windows 10) but the reason is probably that the Unicode code point appears to be 2020 and not 0086.

Comment: @shaochuancs - updated as promised, although I see many other answers arrived whilst I was walking my dog. As long as you have a method that works, it's all good :-)