# attr.data-icon is not working in angular 4

Tags: javascript, typescript, utf-8, angular2-template

I want to load the fonts dynamically in my angular 5 project and it is working fine when I use

`<i data-icon="&#xe04a;" ></i>`

but when I load the value dynamically in angular 5 by  using

`<i [attr.data-icon]="w" ></i>`

In the component.ts file w value is same
`w= "&#xe04a;"`
 then its not working.

But when I saw in console both scenarios then for the first scenario data-icon value turns into an utf code but for the [attr.data-icon] it show the value `"&#xe04a;"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert Unicode character into JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13093126/insert-unicode-character-into-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

When using dynamic data, you should use `w = String.fromCharCode(0x04a)` or `w = '\u004A'`

Please, refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13094667/8038345