# How to use UTF-8 literals in JavaScript alert functions?

Tags: javascript, unicode

Suppose we have a UTF-8 string (represented by a string of hex bytes in character form) that might include an emoji, or any other Unicode characters. How do we represent the string as a literal in JavaScript for use in the `alert` function? In PHP, there are two easy ways: (1) `"\xE2\x96\xB6"` (2) `hex2bin('E296B6')`. I'm having trouble doing the same thing in pure JavaScript. `'\xE2\x96\xB6'` doesn't seem to work (it displays a paragraph mark instead of a right solid triangle in an `alert` function).

I thought of writing a 'hex2bin' function to return the argument as a hex byte string, but JavaScript has no such datatype. In PHP, strings can contain any bit patterns, but I don't think this is true for JavaScript.

I know that JavaScript is a modern language that supports Unicode, so there must be an easy way to do this.

Note that any answer that talks about the `\u` construct is wrong, since \u does not accept a UTF-8 string. UTF-8 is currently the standard and recommended for most storage of character strings, yet most programming languages do not yet offer simple literal syntax for UTF-8 byte strings.

When programmers talk about low-level representations for Unicode, they are frequently interested in UTF-8, since it is the standard and an efficient encoding. UTF-16 and Unicode code points (and the many odd encodings) are of interest, particularly for naming characters (`U+HHHH` notation) and for representing them in fixed widths. But it is UTF-8 that is the standard, and we need more answers on Stack Overflow to help us with UTF-8.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert Unicode character into JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13093126/insert-unicode-character-into-javascript)

Comment: Just write `'▶'`. (Or `'\u25B6'` if you don't trust your file encoding.)

Comment: `\u25B6`looks like a Unicode code point (the actual index in the list of all Unicode characters). This is not UTF-8. The whole advantage of UTF-8 is that it uses the fewest bytes to encode every Unicode character, even the ones with one byte, or six or more bytes.

Comment: @Bergi closed this question as a duplicate. He is wrong but gives me no way to reply to him. The question he cites has only Unicode code point answers (\u) and does not deal with UTF-8 at all.

Comment: @DavidSpector You're replying just fine in the comments to me :-) Your question was "*How do we represent the string as a literal in JavaScript for use in the alert function?*", and the answer to that is to encode your script as UTF-8 and directly embed `'▶'`, as the duplicate target points out. It's unclear what else you are looking for. Maybe [edit] your question to clarify what you mean by "*we have a UTF-8 string*". Where do you have that and what do you want to do with it?

Comment: "*strings can contain any bit patterns, but I don't think this is true for JavaScript.*" - not exactly. Strings in javascript are charcode sequences, and *can* contain any bit patterns in 16-bit values (UCS16). If you are looking for individual bytes, use an `Uint8Array`.

Comment: My question asked for UTF-8 literals (constructed as usual by hex bytes). The selected answer does that perfectly. Your "duplicate question" has nothing to do with UTF-8. However, now that I know that ordinary JavaScript strings are allowed to contain any bit patterns, I can write a function to take a character string containing hex bytes as characters and turn it into a string of hex bytes. The \u notation is only useful for UTF-16 code points, which cannot express all of Unicode. Also, what I have in any UTF-8 file (for example) is bytes, not actual characters, which is why I can't use ▶.

Comment: @Bergi, please remove the notice you added at the top. It is not relevant.

Comment: @DavidSpector There is no such thing as an "UTF-8 literal" in JavaScript, there are no strings containing individual bytes (unless you only use the LSB)."*what I have in any UTF-8 file is bytes*" - that's exactly what `▶` is. You just put these bytes into the JS source file. Btw, [ES6 introduced `\u{…}` escapes](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes#unicode-code-point) which can represent all unicode code points.

Comment: @DavidSpector I've edited the duplicate links to something more relevant for your use case

Comment: They are NOT duplicates and NOT relevant. They both deal with converting one datatype to another, not with UTF-8 literals. A literal is a way to write a UTF-8 string in a JavaScript program without using UTF-8 in the program. There are several possible reasons why this could be needed. Please delete the "duplicate question" heading from this question, thanks. And yes, I know there is only a "Unicode" literal and no UTF-8 literal in JavaScript as yet. That is why I asked for a workaround and got it (see Answer 1). (Aside: why do we have to fight so hard when we use Stack Overflow?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `decodeURIComponent`, which recognises UTF8 hex codes, when prefixed with "%":

```js
console.log(decodeURIComponent("%E2%96%B6"));
```

Comment: Thanks1 This is exactly what I'm looking for.  This method will work with any UTF-8 encoded string as a literal. Perfect. Now all they have to do is build a simpler version right into a future version of JavaScript.