# How to write HTML symbols (&nbsp; &mdash etc.) in Vue application

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have getter in vuex in my application named getTranslation
There are a lot of fields in this getter. And some vaules should have HTML symbols (such as `&nbsp;`)

```
{
...
"E-mail": "e&nbsp;posta",
...
}
```

In some components of my application I use this getter:

```
<p>
  {{ getTranslations['E-mail'] }}
</p>
```

But when a component is rendered I get a string where the HTML symbol is NOT rendered `e&nbsp;posta`

If I look in devtools on rendered string I see this:
`e&amp;nbsp;`

So at first `&` renders as `&amp;` and then `nbsp;` is added

Can someone please help me to fix this behavior. How should I solve this problem?

I tried to use escape symbols ('`\&`' or '`\\&`'). But no success

Comment: Do you want to resolve these characters?

Comment: Html entities belong to html. Unless you use v-html, you cannot use them and don't need them. You can just paste a char that doesn't exist on the keyboard

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13093126/insert-unicode-character-into-javascript

Comment: Rule of thumb usually is to use"entities" of the **source** data file format, not the **target**.  If your source data is UTF-8 JSON you can either use literal no breaking space or its representation (`\u00A0`). If it is JavaScript file, you can use `\xA0` or `\u{A0}` on top of that. Vue should handle it correctly and depending on target context use appropriate representation.