# Get html-escaped text from textarea with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I have a `<textarea id="mytextarea"></textarea>`.

Let's say a user typed in there: `<hello>, world!`

How to get `res = "&lt;hello&gt;, world!";` from what user typed?

This code doesn't work:

```
var res = $('#mytextarea').val().html();
```

It says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

P.S. `var res = $('#mytextarea').val();`  works just fine, but I need the text from the textarea became html-escaped.

How to do it with jQuery?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I escape html special chars in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234773/can-i-escape-html-special-chars-in-javascript)

Comment: @Haradzieniec: i have added a working demo...

Comment: Why it is duplicate, if it is not. I saw that question you've mentioned before I asked. I was curious if it is possible to do WITH jQuery.

Comment: And I answered straight away with the solution..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Already answered: [Can I escape html special chars in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234773/can-i-escape-html-special-chars-in-javascript)

```
function escapeHtml(unsafe) {
    return unsafe
         .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
         .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
         .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
         .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
         .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
}

var res = escapeHtml($('#mytextarea').val());
```

Answer (score 5):

Something like this could work:

```
var res = $("<div/>").text($('#mytextarea').val()).html();
```

Comment: why the downvotes? this does exactly what the op asked.

Answer (score -1):

> - **demo :** http://so.devilmaycode.it/get-html-escaped-text-from-textarea-with-jquery/

use this function that emulate the equivalent php function

> - http://phpjs.org/functions/htmlentities/
> - http://phpjs.org/functions/get_html_translation_table/

---

> - http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php