# display article in database but it has html tag

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, ejs, embedded-javascript

I'm creating a web using nodejs, `ExpressJS, EJS` and `MySQL`.
I save some data with `HTML` code in `MySQL`.
When I get data from `MySQL` and show in web,an error occur: HTML tag in data also showing with data.
How can you help me solve this problem.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to pass your output through a function such as:

```
function escapeHtml(unsafe) {
    return unsafe
         .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
         .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
         .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
         .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
         .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
 }
```

Shamelessly copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234773/can-i-escape-html-special-chars-in-javascript).