# innerText property is not encoding the html

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to assign  the comment text  to an element, which is supposed to contain some html. So I am trying to encode the comment text before displaying it on the page after submitting. I have tried the following procedure but its not encoding the html. I want the html to be converted to literals.

```
                var span=document.createElement("span");
                span.innerText=commenttext;
                console.log(span.innerText);
```

**Edit**

1) `commenttext` is a variable.

2) by literals I mean encoded html... &lt.. etc

Comment: I think I misunderstood this one, what exactly does *"converted to literals"* mean ?

Comment: I think he means escaping. In which case look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234773/can-i-escape-html-special-chars-in-javascript

Comment: So what you want is ***HTML entities***? Javascript doesn't really have a entity encode function, as it's generally not something you'd need on the clientside.

Comment: The description of `innerText` say that it does the encoding automatically and displays html as literals

According MSDN

`If you attempt to assign HTML to an element with InnerText, the HTML code will display as literals in the document`

Comment: Well, literals, as in literal text, not being parsed as HTML. It does **not** mean HTML entities

Comment: So your string contains `&lt;` and you want to display it as `<`? Or the opposite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have jQuery take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1219983/3423729):

```
function htmlEncode(value){
    //create a in-memory div, set it's inner text(which jQuery automatically encodes)
    //then grab the encoded contents back out.  The div never exists on the page.
    return $('<div/>').text(value).html();
}
```

And you would then use that method in your code like

```
var span=document.createElement("span");
span.innerText=htmlEncode(innerText);
console.log(span.innerText);
```

Alternatively take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7124052/3423729) if you don't want to use jQuery.

Comment: hurray.. hhh.. I once read this question then I closed the window.. later I searched and searched and searched but could not find it again.. hhh

Comment: So does it take care of your problem then?

Answer (score 1):

The code below simply replaces `< with &lt; and > with &gt;`.  This works for simple cases, but one should really escape characters & " and ' as well.

```html
<html>
<body>

<div id="output">out</div>
  
<script type="text/javascript">

  var commenttext = '<ul><li style="color:red;">This is a comment</ul>';

  var span=document.createElement("span");

  span.innerHTML=commenttext;

  // displays: This is a comment
  console.log( 'console: ' + span.textContent );
  
  //displays: "<ul><li style="color:red;">This is a comment</li></ul>"
  console.log( span.innerHTML ); 

  //displays: "<ul><li style="color:red;">This is a comment</li></ul>"
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = span.innerHTML.replace(/</g,'&lt;').replace(/>/g,'&gt;');
  

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

read the differences between innerTXT and innerHTML, they are not the same!
The **innerText** property sets or returns the text content of the specified node, and all its descendants.

The innerHTML property sets or returns the HTML content (inner HTML) of an element.