# Adding programmatically a span tag with an anchor inside innertext

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a span element using:

```
ele= document.createElement(span);
ele.innerText = "bla bla (<a href='https://www.pepe.com'> ble ble </a>) blu blu";
divele.appendChild(ele); #divele is an div in the page
```

The problem is the  tag is not showed as a link, it is showed literally.

Comment: Use `ele.innerHTML` and remove the parenthesis around the anchor

Comment: Possible duplicate of [innerText property is not encoding the html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30426903/innertext-property-is-not-encoding-the-html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be `innerHTML` instead of `innerText` (since the sting contains HTML in it). The `span` should be enclosed with single quotes (`''`) or double quotes (`""`).

```js
var ele= document.createElement('span');
ele.innerHTML = "bla bla (<a href='https://www.pepe.com'> ble ble </a>) blu blu";
var divele = document.getElementById('divele');
divele.appendChild(ele);
```

```html
<div id="divele"><div>
```

Comment: Yes, I fixed de " in the post and you are right my problem was I used innerText instead of  innerHTML. Thanks.