# How to apply & nbsp on html while using innerText method in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a terminal app in javascript. But the problem is that I can't use innerHTML method. I tried using innerText method, but it doesnt apply multi space and & nbsp; is also ignore.
For example:

```
example.innerText = "a&nbsp;&nbsp;b"; //output is not 'a  b'
```

I would be glab if someone could help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [innerText property is not encoding the html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30426903/innertext-property-is-not-encoding-the-html)

Comment: Perhaps this link will enlighten you. https://dirask.com/posts/JavaScript-no-break-non-breaking-space-in-string-jMwzxD

Comment: In your example you can also just add normal spaces.

Comment: But why use two non-breaking spaces instead of using CSS? If you're writing a terminal app, pretty sure you _need_ `white-space: pre` already anyway, to make sure that any whitespace sequence doesn't get collapsed to a single space, or even nothing? With `pre` active, you don't need non-breaking spacing, normal spaces work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&nbsp;` works for HTML, but not for text. `.innerText` deals with visible text while `.textContent` recognizes visible and hidden text, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24428100/2813224) for details.

```js
document.querySelector(".test").textContent = "A\u00A0\u00A0B";
```

```html
<p>AB</p>
<p class="test"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

`example.textContent = 'This\u00a0 thing'`

Or

`example.textContent = 'This\u00a0\u00a0thing'`

Answer (score 1):

Why use non-breaking spaces when you can use CSS and normal spaces? If you're writing a terminal app, pretty sure you need `white-space: pre` already anyway since you're probably using a monospace font and use spaces to align ouput, so just keep using that:

```css
.preeformatted { white-space: pre; }
code { background: #DDD; font-variant: small-caps; font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<p class="preeformatted">let's use spaces instead of <code>&amp;nbsp;</code>:   a    b</p>
```