# How to transform plain text to html JSX in ReactJS

Tags: html, dom, reactjs

I have component like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import Autolinker from 'autolinker';

class Comment extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    render(){
        return <li className="media comment">
            <div className="image">
                <img src={this.props.activity.user.avatar.small_url} width="42" height="42" />
            </div>
            <div className="body">
                <p>
                    <strong>{this.props.activity.user.full_name}</strong>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>
                    {Autolinker.link(this.props.activity.text)}
                </p>
            </div>
        </li>;
    }
}

export default Comment;
```

Autolinker returns me a string value like this:

```
"So basically <a href="http://www.silastar.com/dev-sila" target="_blank">silastar.com/dev-sila</a> is perfect and works correctly?"
```

How to convert this string to html JSX so that anchor link would appear as link not as plain text??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html):

```
<p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: Autolinker.link(this.props.activity.text)}} />
```

Comment: This solution imposes XSS security threat if `this.props.activity.text` is not sanitized. The [common approach to sanitizing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6234804/5763764) html characters unfortunately distorts some URLs for Autolinker.