# Print html text with tag in new window

Tags: javascript, html

I need to print in a new window with a string html tags html.
What I did is:

```
function printNewTab(toPrint, title) {
   var newWin = window.open("about:blank");
   newWin.document.write("<html><head><title>" + title + "</title></head></html>");
   newWin.document.write(toPrint.toString());
   console.log(title + ":");
   console.log(toPrint);
}
```

but if I have a string like this:

```
var s = "<h1>title<u> number</u> 1</h1>";
```

and use the method above:

```
printNewTab(s, "title");
```

I obtain a new window where the text does not display tags but is formatted in html.

While I'd really like to see printed `<h1>title<u> number</u> 1</h1>`. 
How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you html encode your string so that symbols like `<` become `&lt`, it will work.

`document.write("&lt;h1&gt;");` will print `<h1>`.

By the way, jQuery`s text() function does this for you.

```
function escapeHtml(unsafe) {
    return unsafe
         .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
         .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
         .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
         .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
         .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
 }

document.write(escapeHtml("<h1>title<u> number</u> 1</h1>"));
```

This will print `<h1>title<u> number</u> 1</h1>`.

function taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234773/can-i-escape-html-special-chars-in-javascript). Credits to @bjornd.

Comment: Mmm ok, but I'd need something more general because H1 was just an example. The string may be composed of any html tags.

Comment: You just create a function to replace all the tags for you. I will add an example

Answer (score 0):

Convert all the html characters to entities, possibly, like this:

```
str = str.replace('&', '&amp;').replace('<', '&lt;').replace('>', '&gt;');
```

Order does not matter EXCEPT that the ampersand replace MUST BE FIRST or else it will create strange behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I obtain this error: `Uncaught TypeError: toPrint.replace is not a function`..

Comment: Give me the result of "typeOf toPrint" from the console

Comment: Actually, convert toPrint to a string before doing the replace.

Comment: I change my code to `function printNewTab(toPrint, title) {
   var s = toPrint.toString();
   console.log("typeOf toPrint: " + toPrint.typeOf);
   console.log("typeOf s: " + s.typeOf);
   var newWin = window.open("about:blank");
   newWin.document.write("<html><head><title>" + title + "</title></head></html>");
   s = s.replace('&', '&amp;').replace('<', '&lt;').replace('>', '&gt;');
   newWin.document.write(s);
}
` but results are of typeOf alway `undefined`. There's something wrong in my code..

Comment: Replace "s.typeOf" with "typeOf s"