# Printing PHP script as plain text using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to create a preview HTML division wherein I face a challenge. 
When I try to get code from the textarea and print it in the HTML, I could not see the PHP code. Here's are my codes,
**HTML Where the code from textarea will be printed**

```
<pre id='pques'></pre>
```

**jQuery code** that will **take value from textarea** and put in the above HTML pretty print area:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    setInterval(function(){
        $("#pques").html($("#eques").val());
    } 
});
```

**Value inside the textarea** with **id=eques**

> What will be the output of the following php code?
>   `<div class="code"><?php  $num  = 1; $num1 = 2; print $num . "+". $num1 ; ?> </div>`

Someone kindly help me to achieve this. I want somewhat similar functionality to the stack overflow question preview stuff.

Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6234808/4202224) answer. You can use `.text()` instead of `.html()`

Comment: empiric, This looks way better. Thank you. But I want only the PHP codes to be escaped. The `<div class="code"></div>` must be printed as HTML and `<?php $num... ?>` must be printed as PHP plain text. Might be a work with RegExp. Help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to escape the angle brackets in the PHP open and closing tags as HTML entities:

`<?php .. ?>` becomes `&lt;?php ... ?&gt;` - PHP will not treat this as server code and will ignore it, but the browser will display `&lt;` as `<` and `&gt;` as `>`. This way you don't need JavaScript to do it, you can print it directly to the page. I would advise always HTML encoding any PHP code that is input on your site, and storing it with entities rather than executable code.

Answer (score 0):

As you use jquery, you can achieve this as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816/escaping-html-strings-with-jquery)

This will escape the brackets as @kallum-tanton already pointed out.