# Angular2 Update dynamically created component.

Tags: angular

I was solving a problem how to dynamically create a component received by API. The solution working for me is

```
private addComponent(template: string) {
    @Component({template: template})
    class TemplateComponent {}

    @NgModule({declarations: [TemplateComponent], imports: [BlogAppModule]})
    class TemplateModule {}

    const mod = this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync(TemplateModule);
    const factory = mod.componentFactories.find((comp) =>
      comp.componentType === TemplateComponent
    );

    this.blogAppRef = this.container.createComponent(factory);
}
```

REF: [Angular2 - Dynamic components in content received by API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42215288/angular2-dynamic-components-in-content-received-by-api/42247835#42247835)

Now, whenever there this function is called it creates a new ng-component and the components just pile one above another. For now, I use this removal code:

```
... 
    if (this.blogAppRef) {
        this.blogAppRef.destroy();
    }

    this.blogAppRef = this.container.createComponent(factory);
}
```

which works fine. But my question is, can this be done better? 
Are there some significant cons about this solution? (memory/power)

I wasn't able to find how to update such dynamically created component. It would require the newly compiled component to replace the previous one;  more precisely replace the internal part of ng-content.

Thanks!

Comment: Please be more specific about what "how to update such dynamically created component" means.

Comment: "replace the previous one" is by destroying the old one and creating a new one. Your code seems to already do that.

Comment: "replace the internal part of ng-content." is not really part of the component, but ruther the parent components content that is projected to the dynamic component. Your dynamic component doesn't show anything about "ng-content".

Comment: Gunter, thanks! ng-component is created by Angular. the content I need is then inside <ng-content> </ng-content>.
Maybe my solution is good, but usually destroying and creating anything smells a bit.

Comment: Your question shows nothing about `ng-component` or `ng-content`. I don't understand how these are related to your question.

Comment: <ng-content> is what I see angular created automatically.