# Converting Dynamic HTML content to Angular components

Tags: angularjs

I have an Angular4 application, which received HTML content over Web-Sockets and gets displayed in a DIV inside one of the Angular Component.

The received HTML content may contain some elements that can be converted to Angular components. Since the web sockets are running out side the Angular context, how can force angular engine scan the dynamic HTML content and convert them to components.

Thanks in advance for all your suggestions.

Ravi.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38577347/how-do-i-manually-sanitize-in-angular2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do I manually sanitize in angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38577347/how-do-i-manually-sanitize-in-angular2)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i understand DOM sanitization is mainly to deal with XSS attacks. But what i am looking at is the way to notify & force Angular engine that the DOM is modified and there could be possible HTML elements that could be converted to Angular Elements.