# Is this a safe way to strip html tags using js?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to strip html tags from a string. I dislike using regex as there will always be someone who finds a way to break it. However using dom poses obvious risks.

How about using `createDocumentFragment`?

```
function striptags(content) {
  var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
  var innerEl = document.createElement('div');
  frag.appendChild(innerEl);
  innerEl.innerHTML = content;
  return frag.firstChild.innerText;
}
striptags('<script>alert("xss attack!")</script>');
```

Comment: What about simply replacing `<` and `>` with `&lt;` and `&gt;`?

Comment: Why not *escape* html tags instead of stripping them?

Comment: Why are you displaying the string as HTML and not text?

Comment: @x-ray I am not looking to escape the html, but to strip it.

Comment: What would you like `striptags("<p>Text</p>")` to return?

Answer (score -1):

> Is this a safe way to strip html tags using js?

No, and using a document fragment doesn't help anything. While [`innerHTML` will not evaluate `<script>`s](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1197575/1048572), your approach is still susceptible to other XSS practices (e.g. `striptags('<img src="" onerror="alert(\'xss attack!\')"></img>')`).

---

Just remove or replace the things that you want to get rid of using a regex, and then [*escape*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234773/can-i-escape-html-special-chars-in-javascript) the rest (which you should do anyway).

```
function striptags(content) {
  return escapeHtml(content.replace(/<\/p>/g, "\n\n")
                           .replace(/<br[^>]*>/g, "\n")
                           .replace(/<[^>]*>/g, ""));
}
```

Comment: Obligatory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @epascarello Yes - I don't care if it misses something, I just want to get rid of a few patterns. The rest will be escaped.

Comment: @epascarello And assuming a browser environment, I don't know any builtin proper HTML parser that is XSS-safe ([unless xml is an option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)), so regex appears to be the best bet. In *valid* HTML, my solution will strip all tags, in invalid html what does "stripping tags" mean at all?

Comment: The reason I asked about 'createDocumentFragment' is: "They are never part of the main DOM tree." therefore I thought they wouldn't be able to cause any harm. Actually removing simple tags using regex and escaping the rest might work for me just fine.

Comment: @Mykybo Yes, they're not part of the rendered `document`, but they still live in the same document and window.