# How to escape HTML but do not escape character entities?

Tags: javascript, html, html-escape-characters

I have to escape an arbitrary string and then assign to innerHTML.

But the string may has already contain character entities, like

```
var str1 = "A &amp; B & C";
var str2 = "A &gt; B > C";
var str3 = "A&qout;B&qout; C &qout;";
```

And I want to get

```
A & B & C 
A > B > C
A"B" C "
```

The question is that how to escape "&" but do not escape "& in other character entities"?

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234773/can-i-escape-html-special-chars-in-javascript

Comment: Why escape if you assign to innerHTML? Only < needs escaping or replacing with &lt; and only if there is no space after it

Comment: @hackerrdave nope, it's not the answer I want :(

Comment: @mplungjan I need to escape due to security

Comment: what about prepared sql statements at api side? than text is text and only interpreted as text, not as script.

Comment: @chenyuxian it is an dublicate. they do exactly what you want and what our answers like.

Comment: it's `&quot;`, not `&qout;` ? ;)

Comment: http://www.htmlhelp.com/de/reference/html40/entities/special.html both answers work with each of this special chars if you add the filter, and much more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First unescape, so replace `&amp;` with `&`, and then escape.

Example:

```js
function unescapeHtml(unsafe) {
    return unsafe
         .replace(/&amp;/g, "&")
         .replace(/&lt;/g, "<")
         .replace(/&gt;/g, ">")
         .replace(/&quot;/g, '"')
         .replace(/&#039;/g, "'")
      
}

function escapeHtml(unsafe) {
    return unsafe
         .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
         .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
         .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
         .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
         .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
}
function setText(id, text){

   document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = escapeHtml(unescapeHtml(text))
} 

var str1 = "A &amp; B & C";
var str2 = "A &gt; B > C";
var str3 = "A&amp;B&amp;C"
var str4 = "A&quot;B&quot; C &quot;"
   
setText("container1", str1); 
setText("container2", str2);
setText("container3", str3);
setText("container4", str4);
```

```html
<div id="container1"></div>
<div id="container2"></div>
<div id="container3"></div>
<div id="container4"></div>
```

Comment: escaping special chars & and ; not required in javascript regex?

Comment: if the string is "A&amp;B&amp;C", then do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: @TypedSource It's not needed, see running snippet.

Comment: @chenyuxian that one is also working, updated the example

Comment: @Julian oh!OK! but it seems like &qout; do not work?

Comment: @chenyuxian added `&quot`. Works now

Comment: @TypedSource officially I think we should escape `&` and `;`. Not in Javascript, but I doesn't hurt: https://regex101.com/r/1s0TyD/2

Answer (score 0):

```
var str1 = "A &amp; B & C";
var str2 = "A &gt; B > C";
var str3 = "A &amp; B &amp; C &gt; D &lt; X";

str1 = str1.replace(/\&amp\;/g, '&');
str2 = str2.replace(/\&gt\;/g, '>');
str3 = str3.replace(/\&amp\;/g, '&').replace(/\&gt\;/g, '>').replace(/\&lt\;/g, '<');

console.log(str1);
console.log(str2);
console.log(str3);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fkherav8/2/

Comment: if the string is "A&amp;B&amp;C", then do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: thank you, but it seems like this method does not work on &qout; ?

Comment: i tried it and it works: `.replace(/\&quot\;/g, '"')` https://jsfiddle.net/fkherav8/3/

Comment: this is the same approach as mine ;) Maybe a bit less verbose

Comment: @chenyuxian it's `&quot;` not `&qout` ? ;)

Comment: @Julian hmmmm... I think I am too tired, thank you guys