# Replacing '<' & '>' with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string

I am trying to append a parsed email to a `textarea` with javascript, and this is proving to be particularly difficult because of the `<` & `>` in email addresses like `<foo@bar.com>`

Here is an example of my situation in action. 
https://jsfiddle.net/xxchz97L/

So I am trying to do a `str.replace` on the `<` & `>` but nothing I do seems to work. Does anyone know how to do this?

Here is a simple excerpt of my code.
I am also including jQuery.

**HTML**

```
<textarea class="form-control template_data" id="content" name="content" rows="8" cols="80"></textarea>
```

**Javascript**

```
var my_text = "From: Foo Bar <foo@bar.com> Date: Sat, Apr 8, 2017 at 2:29 PM";
var regEx = '/<|>/g';
my_text.replace(regEx, "*");
my_text = my_text.replace("&lt;", "*");
my_text = my_text.replace("&gt;", "*");
$('#content').append(my_text);
alert(my_text);
```

**PS**

I figured there would be no way to append `< | >` into a `textarea` as html would think I was posting HTML. If there is someone that does know how to do this please let me know.

Comment: Why not `my_text.replace("<", "*").replace(">", "*");` ?

Comment: regex = /[<>]/g

Comment: if i use following in your fiddle, it works: `my_text = my_text.replace("<", "*");
my_text = my_text.replace(">", "*");`  Use < > instead of codes

Comment: You can include those characters in the `<textarea>` if you turn them into HTML entities (convert `<` to `&lt;` and so on). You don't have to turn them all into asterisks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the RegExp, is very easy :)

```
var regEx = new RegExp("[<>]","g");
```

for replace use:

```
yourString = yourString.replace(regEx, "yourReplace");
```

Do not forget the immutability of the string

Comment: So you cleared all the line breaks then ran it. That seems like a pretty clean solution.

Comment: Not only that, but had a detail in the first replace, which was not reassigning to the String. You will not even need the other two "replace"

Comment: @ThomasValadez why do you want to change the characters to "*"? Why not just HTML-escape them?

Comment: @Pointy I was experimenting with a few things, I figured that would be the easiest option. Are you talking about something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234773/can-i-escape-html-special-chars-in-javascript

Comment: I'm talking about something like my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

A general HTML sanitizer function really only needs one `.replace()` call:

```
var sanitize = function() {
  var map = { "<": "&lt;", ">": "&gt;", "&": "&amp;" },
      rx = /[<&>]/g;

  return function(text) {
    return text.replace(rx, function(match) {
      return map[match];
    };
  };
}();
```

The `.replace()` callback takes each matched special character and uses it as a key to lookup the replacement in a map.

With this, you can preserve the actual content for the `<textarea>` if you use the function on the contents when the page is prepared.

Note that you don't have to worry about this when setting the `.value` property of the `<textarea>` with JavaScript.

Comment: sorry to be asking a dumb question , but on what does this function get called on and who is passing `text` into the first inner function ?

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik The function to call is `sanitize()`. If you were to call `sanitize("<b>Hello World</b>")` the return value would be the string `"&lt;b&gt;Hello World&lt;/b&gt;"`

Comment: perfect ! got it :)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to replace the escaped characters when no such characters exist in the string.

Change:

```
my_text = my_text.replace("&lt;", "*");
my_text = my_text.replace("&gt;", "*");
```

to:

```
my_text = my_text.replace("<", "*");
my_text = my_text.replace(">", "*");
```

Comment: Awesome that worked for the first line. Now I have two questions. Why doesn't the regex expression take care of that? and how would I make it span multiple lines of text?

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem seems to be an incorrect RegEx.
Try the following:

```
my_text = my_text.replace(/(\<|\>)/g, '');
```