# How can I get the decoded string in javascript returning from an API

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am receiving the following data inside my API

```
Jacob&#039;s Syndrome
```

When I show it using foreach loop, the outcome comes as

```
Jacob's Syndrome
```

I want the decoded data `(Jacob's Syndrome)` that I am receiving from the API in order to store it in an array. Can anyone help me what sort of encoding / decoding do I have to perform?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML Entity Decode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796718/html-entity-decode)

Comment: From server side convert from html entity to normal string then return to JS. Depending on server side technology the function will change.

Comment: Note that the first string is HTML, while the second one is text. HTML can contain a lot more than just text...

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234773/can-i-escape-html-special-chars-in-javascript