# How to remove HTML tags in Rich Text area Fields?

Tags: javascript, html, salesforce

I am using a Rich Text Field, and after entering some data it displays it in HTML font, I have tried  `Escape : False` also but it is not working. Here is my code:

```
function GetDescription()
{
    try
    {
        var assetId = '{!JSENCODE(objAsset.Id)}';
        Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
            '{!$RemoteAction.RemoterAssetDetailView.GetDescription}',
            assetId ,
            function(result, event) {
                if(event.status)
                {
                    var jobjAsset = JSON.parse(result);
                    var strDescription = '';
                    for(var i=0;i<jobjAsset.length;i++)
                    {
                        strDescription +=html_encode(jobjAsset[i][NameSpacePrefix + "DescriptionText__c"]);
                    }
                    j$("#divSpecification").html(strDescription);
                }
                else
                {
                }
            },
            {
                escape: false
            }
        );
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        //alert(e);
    }
```

Comment: What is your problem exactly ? You want to escape special html characters ?

Comment: yes i got that issue.can u help me how to reslove it.!!

Answer (score 0):

A possible answer to your question is this pretty simple function created by [@bjornd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/367960/bjornd), which is available [right here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6234804/7804279).
Is function handle the basic HTML special chars, and should solve your problem.

**EDIT:** The `escape` function has been deprecated, as [@Zeke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3654197/zeke) mentionned below. This is not anymore the correct way to do so.

If you want to escape special characters from your string, you should use the `escape` function in Javascript. This function basically converts any special characters, like `<` or `>` into their hexadecimal escape sequence.

```
escape('äöü');        // "%E4%F6%FC"
```

In your case, replace the `html_encode(jobjAsset[i][NameSpacePrefix + "DescriptionText__c"])` with `escape(jobjAsset[i][NameSpacePrefix + "DescriptionText__c"])`

Here is [a link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape) of the Mozilla team documentation about this `escape` function.

Comment: That is a deprecated function and I don't recommend using it. Once it's officially dropped, it's most likely that this application will stop working correctly, if it even works now. Find an alternative instead.

Comment: Befor i am getting value like this <p>Apparatus and method&#39;s for purging flow cells in nucleic acid sequencing instrum &amp; new</p>  Now i am getting %26lt%3Bp%26gt%3BApparatus%20and%20method%26amp%3B%26%2335%3B39%26%2359%3Bs%20for%20purging%20flow%20cells%20in%20nucleic% like this.

Comment: and i have made change in my code like this strDescription +=escape(html_encode(jobjAsset[i][NameSpacePrefix + "DescriptionText__c"]));

Comment: That's normal, it also encode space (" ") as a special character.  But don't use this escape function, the other one I proposed is much better.