# JS math causing total sum to be negative

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to develop a game.

However my math is a problem. Every time the total profit value goes into negative value.

How can i fix it?

```js
var gameProfit = 10000;
var tinyOwned = 0;
var tinyCost = 10000;
var tinyIncome = 0;

function buyTiny(){
 if (gameProfit >= tinyCost){
  
  tinyOwned += 1;
  document.getElementById('tiny-owned').innerHTML = tinyOwned;
  document.getElementById('current-profit').innerHTML = "Profit : $ " + (gameProfit -= tinyCost * tinyOwned);
  document.getElementById('tiny-cost').innerHTML = "Next Cost : $ " + (tinyCost * tinyOwned + 10000);
  document.getElementById('tiny-income').innerHTML = "Income : $ " + (tinyIncome = 15000 * tinyOwned); 
 }
}

var timer = 0;
var timeInterval = 10;

window.setInterval(function gameTimer() {
 if (timer >= 0) {
  timer++;
  document.getElementById('timer-value').style.width = timer + "px";
 }
 if (timer >= 600) {
  timer = 0 + 1;
  document.getElementById('timer-value').style.width = "0px";
  
  tinyIncome = 15000 * tinyOwned;
  gameProfit += tinyIncome;
  
  document.getElementById('current-profit').innerHTML = "Profit : $ " + (gameProfit);
  
 }
}, timeInterval);
```

Can anyone see the problem in my code? gameProfit Variable goes into negative how to fix this?

Comment: Can you provide working example instead of *errors maker*

Comment: Please share HTML code.

Comment: At first if you call the function buyTiny with the value you show us : 
gameProfit (10 000) = gameProfit (10 000) - tinyCost(10 000) * 1 = 0
So after the first call gameProfit is 0
But i can't find where you call this function

Comment: In buyTiny() you have gameProfit -= tinyCost * tinyOwned. After first time your profit is 0.

Comment: And your interval is 10 ms. May be you want to set it for 1 sec or something else?

Comment: yes the profit must be 0 at the first call then after every function gameTimer()  call the profit must increase by interval

Comment: my problem is that when the tinyBuy function is called it can make gameProfit go into engative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You allow someone to buy when: `gameProfit >= tinyCost`

But you reduce gameProfit like: `gameProfit -= tinyCost * tinyOwned`

So you take more then you initially check! to fix:

```
if (gameProfit >= tinyCost * tinyOwned){
```

The math looks really messy especially since it is mixed up with setting InnerHtml. I **strongly advice** to first do the math and then update the Html.InnerHTML

Offtopic: make sure you escape your data if you are ever going to make it to a multiplayer game, else people can crosside script it ([Can I escape html special chars in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234773/can-i-escape-html-special-chars-in-javascript)) but this is something you don't really have to worry about at this stage.

Comment: so first do the math and then add it to html