# Node js .I want to use markdown to save the data securely(for xss) instead of json.stringify() method

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, markdown

I want to use markdown  to save the data securely  instead of json.stringfy() method.Like this exapmle:usercomment is `<script>alert('ss')</script>`

```js
app.get('/comment',function(req.res){
var usercomment=req.body.comment;//from comment textarea(user's comment)
const x=markdown.toHTML(usercomment);
var comments=new comment({user:req.session.nick,comment:x});
comments.save();
console.log(x)

}
```

Or use json.stringify() like this  **I save the usercomment with json.stringify().Later i will send the comment(from database) to html with markdown.toHTML(comment)**:

```js
app.get('/comment',function(req.res){
var usercomment=req.body.comment;
    const x=JSON.stringify(usercomment);
    var comments=new comment({user:req.session.nick,comment:x});
    comments.save();
    console.log(x)

    }
```

**Which one should I use?**

Comment: what's in `usercomment`? Also, neither of the two snippets converts *to* markdown - please clarify

Comment: It's not clear what sort of "security" we're talking about here.

Comment: if your concern is security you should have a look at escape functions instead. Also take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234773/can-i-escape-html-special-chars-in-javascript

Comment: @pointy sould I say -what sort of "security"?json.stringify() -**When sending data to a web server, the data has to be a string.**

Comment: In this site most users look at questions only -How to ask?-.If question is not clear press **-** vote-Yes i understand this.But now my question is very very very clear.So you must answer my question(for negative voters) or you look only -How to ask?-.

Comment: <img></img>ddddd

Comment: [test](javascript://%0d%0aprompt(1))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### JSON and Markdown do not give you security

Neither of the things you mention will magically give you security.
To handle dangerous user input, you need to [sanitize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_sanitization) the input.

A quick search on NPM gives me [sanitize-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitize-html), which seems like it would be good for this purpose.

```
const sanitizeHtml = require('sanitize-html');
app.post('/comment', function(req, res){
    let usercomment = req.body.comment;
    let safe_comment = sanitizeHtml(usercomment);
    let comments = new comment({
        user: req.session.nick,
        comment:safe_comment,
    });
    comments.save();
    res.send('saved');
}
```

If you don't want to allow your users to use any HTML, you can escape the user comment so that their input does not act like HTML. ([htmlencode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/htmlencode) seems good for this purpose)

```
const htmlencode = require('htmlencode');
app.post('/comment', function(req, res){
    let usercomment = req.body.comment;
    let safe_comment = htmlencode.htmlEncode(usercomment);
    let comments = new comment({
        user: req.session.nick,
        comment:safe_comment,
    });
    comments.save();
    res.send('saved');
}
```

Comment: @ŞükranEken Markdown does not automatically escape HTML like that. However, sites like GitHub have implemented their own HTML sanitizer (see [GitHub's](https://github.com/github/markup#github-markup) for example) which runs after the Markdown is converted to HTML. Those sanitizers will escape `<script>` tags etc. If you are running your own site which converts Markdown to HTML, then for security you also need to implement a sanitizer as this answer demonstrates.

Comment: For more information about making Markdown "secure" I suggest reading [Markdown and XSS](https://michelf.ca/blog/2010/markdown-and-xss/).