# want to make view json file data using php

Tags: javascript, php, json

i make a crud system with json file data. i used javascript to view data into a html file. but i think it cause some security issues. i want to make my data view using php not in JavaScript.

this is my JavaScript view file

```
var output = document.getElementById('output');

var ajaxhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

var url = "form.json";

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var details = '';
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

        var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);

                var output = '';

                output += "<table class='table table-bordered'>";
                output += "<tr><th scope='col'>id</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Age</th><th>Action</th></tr>";              

                for(x in response){

                    if(response[x].is_active == "1"){


                    output += "<tr><td>" + response[x].id + "</td><td>" + response[x].firstname + "</td><td>"+response[x].lastname+"</td><td>"+response[x].age+"</td><td><a href='edit.php?id="+response[x].id+"&firstname="+response[x].firstname+"&lastname="+response[x].lastname+"&age="+response[x].age+"' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm active' role='button' aria-pressed='true'>Edit</a><a href='update.php?id="+response[x].id+"&firstname="+response[x].firstname+"&lastname="+response[x].lastname+"&age="+response[x].age+"' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' role='button' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#exampleModal' name='btnDelete' style='margin-left: 10px;'>Delete</a></td></tr>";

                    }

                }

                output += "</table> ";
               document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;

    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xhttp.send();
```

i want to do this same thing using php. can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you want to rewrite that in php ? Please, clarify.

Comment: yes i want to rewrite using php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PHP's `curl` functions to do the equivalent AJAX request from PHP.

You can use `json_decode()` to convert JSON into PHP objects and arrays.

Escape the output with `htmlspecialchars()`.

If you want to fix your JS code, escape everything you got from the database on output. See [Can I escape html special chars in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234773/can-i-escape-html-special-chars-in-javascript) or use jQuery's `.text()` function to populate the table.