# How to slice a part of string using typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, autocomplete

I am building up a custom select box with multi select as like angular material chips..

**HTML**

```
<div class="autocomplete">
    <div class="chips-input-container">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="user-chip" *ngFor="let user of userSelects">
                {{user.name}}
                <span (click)="deleteSelects(user)" class="delete-icon-chip">&#10006;</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 form-label-group">
            <input name="suggestion" type="text" id="autocomplete-input" class="form-control" placeholder="User" (click)="suggest()"
             [(ngModel)]="userSelectsString" (keyup)="onKey($event)" id="autocomplete-input">
            <label for="autocomplete-input" class="emailBox"></label>
            <label class="fa fa-caret-down input-icon"></label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <ul id="autocomplete-results" class="autocomplete-items" *ngIf="show">
        <li *ngFor="let s of suggestions" [ngClass]="isSelected(s) ? 'selected-suggestion' : ''" (click)="selectSuggestion(s)">{{ s.name }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**TS:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
   suggestion: string = '';
  typeahead: FormControl = new FormControl();
  openSelectBox: boolean = false;

  fieldHistory: string[] = [];

  inputValue: string;
  autocomplete_results: any;
  input = document.querySelector('#autocomplete-input');
  userSelectsString = '';
  name = 'Angular';
  userSelects = [];
  suggestions = [{"id":"001","name":"mango"},{"id":"002","name":"apple"},{"id":"003","name":"banana"},{"id":"004","name":"pine"},{"id":"005","name":"orange"},{"id":"006","name":"chery"},{"id":"007","name":"watermelon"},{"id":"008","name":"grapes"},{"id":"009","name":"lemon"}];

  show: boolean = false;

  suggest() {
    this.show = true;
  }

  isSelected(s:any) {
   return this.userSelects.findIndex((item) => item.id === s.id) > -1 ? true : false;
  }

  selectSuggestion(s) {
    this.userSelects.find((item) => item.id === s.id) ? 
    this.userSelects = this.userSelects.filter((item) => item.id !== s.id) :
    this.userSelects.push(s);
    this.show = false;
  }

  deleteSelects(s) {
    this.userSelects = this.userSelects.filter((item) => item.id !== s.id);
  }

  assignToNgModel() {
    this.userSelectsString = '';
    this.userSelects.map((item) => this.userSelectsString += item.name + ' ');
  }

  onKey(e) {
    this.inputValue = e.target.value;

    if (this.inputValue.length > 0) {
      var people_to_show = [];

      this.autocomplete_results = document.getElementById("autocomplete-results");
      this.autocomplete_results.innerHTML = '';
      people_to_show = this.autocomplete(this.inputValue);

      for (let i = 0; i < people_to_show.length; i++) {
        this.autocomplete_results.innerHTML += '<li>' + people_to_show[i] + '</li>';
      }
      this.autocomplete_results.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      people_to_show = [];
      this.autocomplete_results.innerHTML = '';
    }
  }

  autocomplete(val) {
    var people_return = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.suggestions.length; i++) {
      if (val === this.suggestions[i].slice(0, val.length)) {
        people_return.push(this.suggestions[i]);
      }
    }
    return people_return;
  }
}
```

As of selection and deletion part, everything works fine but when i implemented autocomplete, i am unable to get result as i am using slice for the array of objects.

My data is:

```
  suggestions = [{"id":"001","name":"mango"},{"id":"002","name":"apple"},{"id":"003","name":"banana"},{"id":"004","name":"pine"},{"id":"005","name":"orange"},{"id":"006","name":"chery"},{"id":"007","name":"watermelon"},{"id":"008","name":"grapes"},{"id":"009","name":"lemon"}];
```

In the for loop, i am getting error as **Property 'slice' does not exist on type '{ "id": string; "name": string; }'.**  in the line`this.suggestions[i].slice(0, val.length)`,

```
  for (let i = 0; i < this.suggestions.length; i++) {
      if (val === this.suggestions[i].slice(0, val.length)) {
        people_return.push(this.suggestions[i]);
      }
    }
```

If i give any inside `suggestions: any = [{"id":"001","name":"mango"},...}]`, it is showing slice is not a function.

Kindly help me to achieve the result of autocomplete.

**Stackblitz:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-euuvxw

Comment: When you do `this.suggestions[i].slice` your trying to slice an object, not an array

Comment: slice() use with array type not with object.

Comment: This is unrelated to the question, but I hope you're aware that adding strings into `innerHTML` without escaping can lead to security problems if they come from a source that you don't control and contain HTML code.  You can [escape the HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234773/can-i-escape-html-special-chars-in-javascript).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to slice the name, not the entire suggestion object.  And looking at how you are using the result, you probably want to push only the name into `people_return` too:

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.suggestions.length; i++) {
  if (val === this.suggestions[i].name.slice(0, val.length)) {
  //                              ^^^^
    people_return.push(this.suggestions[i].name);
  }
}
```

Comment: It is showing the result list as ```[object Object]```, if i type ```man``` for mango in input box..

Comment: But i couldn't get the list view as i have shown in the stackblitz.. Is it because i am using javascript i am unable to get the result like onclick?

Comment: It would be much more helpful if you help me to fix that part, as i am beginner i couldn't move forward with it.. I am sorry for the same.. If you update that also it would be better solution for me..

Comment: I went to the stackblitz and just saw a page with "Hello Angular! Start editing to see some magic happen :)".  Did you save the stackblitz after your latest changes?

Comment: It looks like the list styling is generated by your Angular template, and when you overwrite the HTML, you are losing the styling.  I messed around to try to make the autocomplete display go through the Angular template and got something working: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7jepkn .  Caveat: I don't know Angular at all, so my solution may violate Angular expectations and cause problems in the future.

Comment: Thank you @Matt for your valuable time for helping me.. It is useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `slice()` in array type value. In your case it is `this.suggestions` so use `this.suggestions.slice(0, val.length)`

Comment: The dropdown list is coming as empty if i use the above.