# How to turn HTML-format user input into text in prompt

Tags: javascript, html, prompt

I want to have a `prompt` box asking the user for their name. But I'm putting that directly into the page, and if I enter something HTML-y (`<canvas>` for example) then it places that element on the page. How can I make this into text, so instead of making a `<canvas>` element it writes `<canvas>` to the page as text?

```js
var name = prompt("Enter your name: ");
document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = name;
```

```html
<p id="paragraph"></p>
```

Unfortunately I can't use jQuery, so a pure JS solution would be nice.

Comment: You can use innerText, instead of innerHTML

Comment: That works perfectly! Please add an answer with that information for quick future reference.

Comment: There is also [*textContent*](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-node-textcontent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use innerText, instead of innerHTML

```
 document.getElementById("paragraph").innerText = name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to 'escape' the input text before displaying it again.

Your JavaScript would now look like:

```
var name = escapeHtml(prompt("Enter your name: "));
document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = name;

function escapeHtml(unsafe) {
    return unsafe
         .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
         .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
         .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
         .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
         .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
}
```

Note: This code snippet is from 
[Can I escape html special chars in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234773/can-i-escape-html-special-chars-in-javascript)

PSA:
Please don't use client-side sanitation of text for anything related to security.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem was solved earlier.

Comment: Rather than answering with a reference to a duplicate, just mark it as a duplicate. ;-)