# How to create a method for the reuse in two parts ?(typescript, google maps)

Tags: typescript, google-maps, methods

I have a google map, and I have a code that displays the information of a marker when it clicks on it, the codes are almost the same, the variables only differ.
Example: In the first part, I have displayed 5 markers, click on them and the information is displayed:

```
marker.addListener('click', () => {
    //create the content
    let markerInfoTemplate = `
        <span class="title">${this.locations[i][0]}</span><br>
        <span class="address">${this.locations[i][3]}</span><br>
        <button class="text-button">
              <a href="${this.locations[i][4]}">Show route</a>
        </button>
    `;
     this.infowindow.setContent(markerInfoTemplate);
     this.infowindow.open(map, marker);

     //change the markers icons
     this.deselectAllMarkers();
           marker.setIcon(this.activeIcon);
     });
```

the 2nd Code, when looking for ex "catering" and several markers are displayed:

```
currentMarker.addListener('click', () => {
   //create the content
   let markerInfoTemplate = `
       <span class="title">${place.name}</span><br>
       <span class="address">${place.adr_address}</span><br>
             <button class="text-button">
                <a href="${place.url}">Show route</a>
              </button>
   `;

    this.infowindow.setContent(markerInfoTemplate);
    this.infowindow.open(map, currentMarker);

    //change the markers icons
    this.deselectAllMarkers();
       currentMarker.setIcon(this.activeIcon);
    });
```

As I said, the code is the same, except the variables. How can I restructure the code so it is not duplicated?
Should I do a method? How could I do that?

Comment: This part would like to reuse it :                                                                                                        let markerInfoTemplate = `
       <span class="title">${place.name}</span><br>
       <span class="address">${place.adr_address}</span><br>
             <button class="text-button">
                <a href="${place.url}">Show route</a>
              </button>
   `;

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse the entire code snippet if you like.  Assuming all of this code is in a class, you would define a method like this:

```
// TODO: Replace `any` with the correct type for a marker.
setupMarkerClickHandler(marker: any, name: string, address: string, url: string) { 
  marker.addListener('click', () => {
    //create the content
    let markerInfoTemplate = `
        <span class="title">${name}</span><br>
        <span class="address">${address}</span><br>
        <button class="text-button">
              <a href="${url}">Show route</a>
        </button>
    `;
    this.infowindow.setContent(markerInfoTemplate);
    // TODO: Replace `map` with another way of referring to the map (maybe save
    // the map in a property of `this`).
    this.infowindow.open(map, marker);

    //change the markers icons
    this.deselectAllMarkers();
    marker.setIcon(this.activeIcon);
  });
}
```

Then call:

```
this.setupMarkerClickHandler(marker, this.locations[i][0], this.locations[i][3], this.locations[i][4]);
```

and:

```
this.setupMarkerClickHandler(currentMarker, place.name, place.adr_address, place.url);
```

I notice you're inserting strings into HTML without escaping, which could be a security problem if you don't control the source of those strings.  Pick your favorite solution from, e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6234773) to escape the strings.