# Escaping apostrophes in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with an autocomplete search field. It all works well until an apostrophe is used in the search. For now both the var names and the corresponding database names have spaces instead of apostrophes so that these names work.

I know I need to escape the apostrophe (\') and have tried this in the var list but it doesn't work because I'm guessing it needs to be cleaned (as it were) in the javascript code but I don't know how or where.

The code is below (sorry it's so much) and any help would be greatly appreciated:

```js
function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
  /*the autocomplete function takes two arguments,
  the text field element and an array of possible autocompleted values:*/
  var currentFocus;
  /*execute a function when someone writes in the text field:*/
  inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
      var a, b, i, val = this.value;
      /*close any already open lists of autocompleted values*/
      closeAllLists();
      if (!val) { return false;}
      currentFocus = -1;
      /*create a DIV element that will contain the items (values):*/
      a = document.createElement("DIV");
      a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
      /*append the DIV element as a child of the autocomplete container:*/
      this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
      /*for each item in the array...*/
      for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        /*check if the item starts with the same letters as the text field value:*/
        if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() === val.toUpperCase()) {
          /*create a DIV element for each matching element:*/
          b = document.createElement("DIV");
          /*make the matching letters bold:*/
          b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
          b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
          /*insert a input field that will hold the current array item's value:*/
          b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
          /*execute a function when someone clicks on the item value (DIV element):*/
          b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
              /*insert the value for the autocomplete text field:*/
              inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
              /*close the list of autocompleted values,
              (or any other open lists of autocompleted values:*/
              closeAllLists();
          });
          a.appendChild(b);
        }
      }
  });
  /*execute a function presses a key on the keyboard:*/
  inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
      var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
      if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        /*If the arrow DOWN key is pressed,
        increase the currentFocus variable:*/
        currentFocus++;
        /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up
        /*If the arrow UP key is pressed,
        decrease the currentFocus variable:*/
        currentFocus--;
        /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        /*If the ENTER key is pressed, prevent the form from being submitted,*/
        e.preventDefault();
        if (currentFocus > -1) {
          /*and simulate a click on the "active" item:*/
          if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
        }
      }
  });
  function addActive(x) {
    /*a function to classify an item as "active":*/
    if (!x) return false;
    /*start by removing the "active" class on all items:*/
    removeActive(x);
    if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
    if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
    /*add class "autocomplete-active":*/
    x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
  }
  function removeActive(x) {
    /*a function to remove the "active" class from all autocomplete items:*/
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
    }
  }
  function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
    /*close all autocomplete lists in the document,
    except the one passed as an argument:*/
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
        x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  /*execute a function when someone clicks in the document:*/
  document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      closeAllLists(e.target);
  });
}

/*An array containing all the property names:*/
var properties = ["Aigue Marine 10","Aigue Marine 9","Alizés","Amirauté","Arc En Ciel II 295","Belle du Marais","Bien Etre","Bleuets","Bouton d'Or","Bruyeres","Calumet","Cigales 15","Clé des Pins","Clémenceau ","Coquelicot"];

/*initiate the autocomplete function on the "propertynames" element, and pass along the properties array as possible autocomplete values:*/
autocomplete(document.getElementById("propertynames"), properties);
```

```html
<input id="propertynames">
```

In var `properties` I have changed one name as I would like it to be (`"Bouton d'Or"`) and when I type `b` into the search field it, as expected, creates a list of names beginning with `B` as expected but when I choose a name with an apostrophe from the autocomplete list like `Bouton d'Or`, the value it places in the search field is `"Bouton d"` it stops at the apostrophe.

It still does this even if I change the var name to `"Bouton d\'Or"` so that's why maybe I think there should be some specific code inserted at the line:

```
b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
```

but I'm not sure.

I really hope this makes sense.

Comment: What exactly is your issue? What happens and what should happen?

Comment: On which line are you getting an error, if any? And what does it say?

Comment: It looks like you need to HTML escape the apostrophe, not just JS escape it since you are concatenating it to a string of HTML thus `b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i]`.

See [OWASP XSS Cheat Sheet](https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.md#rule-1---html-escape-before-inserting-untrusted-data-into-html-element-content) for a list of characters to escape before appending plain text to HTML.

Comment: [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) may make this a bit easier for you.

Comment: To echo @benvc : `\`Bouton d'Or\``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is the escaping on the html side and not in JavaScript.

The `"<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>"` becomes:

```
<input type='hidden' value='Bouton d'Or'>
```

Or with your `\` escaping it becomes:

```
<input type='hidden' value='Bouton d\'Or'>
```

But in both cases the value of the attribute will end at the `'` before the `Or`, because the `\` is not used for escaping in html.

The proper escaping of `'` in html is `&#x27;`.

```
 "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i].replace(/'/g,'&#x27;') + "'>"
```

And the resulting html will then be:

```
<input type='hidden' value='Bouton d&#x27;Or'>
```

[Can I escape html special chars in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234773/can-i-escape-html-special-chars-in-javascript)

Comment: Isn't there a javascript function to automatically escape the value?

Comment: @GarrettMotzner No, I added a linkt to a question that asks about that topic. You could also query for that element after it was added to the DOM and set its `value` property, then you wouldn't need to care about the html escaping.

Comment: Thank you all very much and t.niese especially … so helpful. What a great place this is!