# json file does not show string inside "< >", on the webpage (eg. "abc <endpoint>")

Tags: json, html-escape-characters

< , > are not considered as escape characters. But when i need to write a script inside a String 
(eg.)     " ....... " [json code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzJwG.png) the corresponding string is not displayed properly on the jaggery webpage, it is displayed as follows [viewed on the webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHi8X.png). where as it should be displayed as follows [how it should show on the jaggery webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHpmQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you insert the text as innerHTML then the tags are interpreted as html tags and are not shown. 
you might find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234773/can-i-escape-html-special-chars-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

& = &amp , < = &lt , > = &gt , " = &quot , ' = &#039