# Is HTML encoding angle brackets, &, newline, and quotes enough to prevent XSS?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, xss

I am creating a website, and I have a section where the user can provide input via a form. The input is sanitized using this:

```
str.replace(/[\x26\x0A<>'"]/g,function(r){return"&#"+r.charCodeAt(0)+";"})
```

After that, the data is placed between `<p>` tags. So something like this:

```
<p id="foo">Random message</p>
```

Is my replacement function good enough to prevent an XSS attack?

Comment: Don't sanitize yourself. Use JavaScript's `innerText` and you are safe.

Comment: @M1K1O I will look into that. Is my current function safe though?

Comment: Rather, use `textContent` if you're setting content.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans They behave differently and both can be appropriate for different uses. E.g. when setting `innerText`  to a string containing a newline, the newline is visible (as a `<br>`), but if you used `textContent` the newline is ignored.

Comment: That's not the true difference: `innerText` is only the node's text, and only _visible_ text, whereas `textContent` is the full tree text content. For getting, you need to make a judgement call on which of the two to use (and even then, usually it's `textContent`). When setting, just use `textContent`, because HTML doesn't care about newlines until you force it to care by giving it CSS that does that (e.g. set `white-space: pre" and you get to see all whitespace including newlines. Which you should almost never need, write proper elements and CSS instead)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically a duplicate of [Can I escape html special chars in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234773/can-i-escape-html-special-chars-in-javascript). Yes your code is probably safe, it does the same as what the accepted answer there does.