# XSS Protection HTML Entities

Tags: javascript, html, security, xss

Do you think that this functions are enough to prevent XSS if used to filter user input? And should I really make my own or use XSS libraries available? Give me constructive criticism please. Thank you everyone.

```
/**
 * Escape HTML string to prevent XSS.
 */
export const escapeHtml = (string: string): string => {
    if (isString(string)) {
        const entityMap = {
            "&": "&amp;",
            "<": "&lt;",
            ">": "&gt;",
            '"': "&quot;"
        };
        return string.slice(0, string.length).replace(/[&<>"]/g, (s: string): string => entityMap[s]);
    }
    return string;
};

/**
 * Loop over Object to escape each of its value to prevent XSS.
 */
export const escapeHtmlQueryObject = (obj: { [string]: string }): { [string]: string } => {
    let result = obj;
    if (obj && isObject(obj)) {
        result = Object.keys(obj).reduce((res: { [string]: string }, key: string): {
            [string]: string
        } => {
            res[key] = escapeHtml(obj[key]);
            return res;
        }, {});
    } else if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production" && process.env.NODE_ENV !== "test") {
        console.error(`FilterXSSQueryObject can't process ${obj.toString()}`);
    }
    return result;
};
```

Comment: Friends don't let friends write their own XSS filters. Not in XXI century. Please look into https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SXbrgvAK_5U and never do it again.

Answer (score 0):

Compared to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6234804/1371131), you may want to escape single quotes also.

That said, if you want to make sure your code is secure, it may be better to rely on a library that has been battle tested by security experts.

People don't like loading libraries for small things, but this is an important small thing, so I wouldn't mind it.

Unrelated: it seems that you're iterating over an object's keys to access its values in a roundabout way using `Object.keys`, but you can also just use `Object.values`.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the response. Can you give me a reason why single quotes needs to be escaped also if I am already escaping most of the 'dangerous' chars? Thank you.

Comment: Dunno for sure, presumably due to string injection into strings declared using single quotes.