# JSON Strings onclick function

Tags: javascript, json

Good evening, I'm trying to send an encoded JSON via the `onclick` attribute.

Unfortunately this JSON contains articulated strings with many apostrophes and quotes.  As you can well understand the JSON closes the quotes of the `onclick` attribute.

## Edit 1

This is in a "return" of jquery DataTables loaded by ajax and the json is obviously different for item so i can't make an addEventListener (correct me if I'm wrong).

i need this `getJsonObj()` function to open a modal with all information inside

```
{data: null,
        render: function (data, type) {
          const json = JSON.stringify(data);
          console.log(json);
          return `<a onclick="event.preventDefault();getJsonObj(${json})"style='cursor: pointer' id='modalApp' class='orange-link uk-text-bold uk-text-uppercase'>${data.full_name}</a>`;
        },
}
```

This is the output:

[image: Example]

Any ideas to be able to send it without problems?

## Edit 2

Im not using any framework, only javascript, jquery, and Jquery datatables

Comment: Encode this json with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: I recommend using `addEventListener` instead of binding event handlers in HTML.

Comment: Are you sure this is jQuery? This looks more like React or Vue.

Comment: Make a design where you do not have to do that! You should not have to stick the whole value in an attribute. Hard to give a solution without knowing the framework.

Comment: @EdwardEllsworth yes, is jquery datatable render function. to render the table cell as you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting a string into HTML so it needs to be HTML escaped. Specifically, in your case, the quotes from the JSON string are closing the quotes from the HTML `onclick` attribute. Use the function below and the quotes in your JSON will be replaced with `&quot;`

```
function escapeHtml(unsafe) {
  return unsafe
    .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
    .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
    .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
    .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
    .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
}

<a onclick="event.preventDefault();getJsonObj(${escapeHtml(json)})"style='cursor: pointer' id='modalApp' class='orange-link uk-text-bold uk-text-uppercase'>${data.full_name}</a>
```

See [Can I escape html special chars in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234773/can-i-escape-html-special-chars-in-javascript)

Comment: And for unescape how can i do it?

Comment: You don't have to unescape it, just like you don't need to unescape characters you've escaped in a JS string such as `Hello\tWorld`. The JS engine will parse it and it will know that it means "Hello[tab]World", and the HTML parsing engine will know that  `<a onclick="alert(&quot;test&quot;)"` is creating a string with the following contents `alert("test")`

Comment: Thanks, very helpful