# Append <script> tag to list as normal text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, chat, nodes

I am making a chat application.
When messages are received the messages are appended to a list: `<ul id="messages"></ul>` with the following code:

```js
$('#messages').append(`<li><span id="messageReceived">${content.bold}</span> ${content.std}</li>`)
```

However when the client sends a message containing `<script>alert('hello world')</script>` the script is executed on all connected clients. This is obviously unsafe.

I would instead like the script to just be appended to the list as `<script>alert('hello world')</script>` just like any other message.

I am using jQuery and full source code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/Alex-Hawking/crunch-app).

Comment: I would initially implement [CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src) and restrict `inline scripts`. Then I would escape HTML characters (`<` for `&lt;` and `>` for `&gt;`) before render as is mentioned in another [SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234773/can-i-escape-html-special-chars-in-javascript).

Comment: Do you need like this? https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/oNzmpvb