# How to display a script tag instead of executing it?

Tags: javascript, html

I just want to show a basic html document in my website, and the text includes script tags.
Is there a way to show:

```
<script>document.write("hi");</script>
```

Instead of `hi`?

Basically i want to **NOT** execute the javascript input.

Comment: You could encode those entities though.

Comment: You have to treat it as a string and escape it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234773/can-i-escape-html-special-chars-in-javascript

Comment: [Duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+display+html+tags+in+html) of [Display HTML snippets in HTML](/q/2820453/4642212). Entities are discussed in any [introduction to HTML](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Getting_started#entity_references_including_special_characters_in_html).

Comment: @Codenewbie Anything different?

Comment: @AloHA_ChiCken yep , removed deprecated and edited

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `pre` tag but need to

> replace all < signs with `&lt;` and all > signs with `&gt;`

```html
<pre>
    &lt;script&gt;document.write("hi");&lt;/script&gt;
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `&lt;` html entity to escape the tag opening interpretation of the opening angle bracket.

```
&lt;script>document.write("hi");&lt;/script>
```

Comment: Do your own answer instead of totally overwriting somebody else's answer.

Comment: on another side, your answer is currently in the "low quality" queue. The edited was not. You should accept the edit, imho.

Comment: On the other hand one should create his own answer instead of totally overwriting somebody else's answer, if one's answer is totally unrelated to the one he is overwriting, even if it's of 'low quality'.

Comment: And, unrelated to that, my answer is currently the only one that is working and it contains the minimal solution to the problem at hand. The other solution contains confusing <pre> tags which make the output different from what was wished for.

Comment: I welcome any independent answer that puts more effort (than I did) to answering this question.

Comment: Ok, now +1 (short solution is cool, with explanations of why it works, it's better)