# Replace text with custom html

Tags: javascript

I want to display text message conversations in my chat app.

My case: When user search some text in search box, message include searchText will be style with red color.
Example:

```
user search: "div"

// messageText = "abc <div>all is text</div>" (searching in plain text here);
// htmlText = "abc &lt;div&gt;all is text&lt;/div&gt;";
// OUTPUT MUST BE: "abc &lt;<span style='color: red'>custom</span>&gt;string &lt;<span style='color: red'>custom</span>&gt"
```

Here is my code:

```js
const origin = "abc <div>all is text </div>"; // text input
const str = "abc &lt;div&gt;all is text &lt;/div&gt;"; // after sanitize

const element = document.createElement("div");
element.innerHTML = str;
for (let node of element.childNodes) {
  // I want replace "div" text with my custom html
  node.textContent = node.textContent.replace(/div/gi, "<span style='color: red'>custom</span>");
}

const result = element.innerHTML;
console.log(result);
```

Here is the `result` output

**Output**

```
abc &lt;&lt;span style='color: red'&gt;custom&lt;/span&gt;&gt;string &lt;/&lt;span style='color: red'&gt;custom&lt;/span&gt;&gt;
```

**Expect**

```
abc &lt;<span style='color: red'>custom</span>&gt;string &lt;<span style='color: red'>custom</span>&gt;
```

Can you help me, tks for your help.

Comment: You need to replace `innerHTML` instead of `textContent`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`node.textContent = ...` will produce valid text, by escaping whatever you pass to it.

If you want to insert HTML instead, use `node.innerHTML`

```js
node.innerHTML = node.textContent.replace(/div/gi, "<span style='color: red'>custom</span>");
```

***Edit*** *I realize your problem is more complex than that. You first need to escape HTML inside your text, and then replace `div` with the HTML you want to insert, and finally use `inneHTML` to apply the result.*

***Edit2*** *After updating your question, I understand you want to search/highlight something within text input. Edited the code to do that*

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6234804/3410989):

```js
function escapeHtml(unsafe) {
  return unsafe
    .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
    .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
    .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
    .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
    .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
}

function highlightSearch(node, query) {
  //Within node, highlight matched text (using replacement "$&")
  //highlight done by surrounding found text with a <span>
  let txt = node.textContent;                 //Get inner text
  console.log('raw text:', txt);
  txt = escapeHtml(txt);                      //Escape text with HTML entities
  console.log('html text:', txt);
  //Search and replace ("$&" = whole matched substring)
  txt = txt.replaceAll(query, "<span style='color: red'>$&</span>");
  console.log('highlighted:', txt);
  //Show result
  node.innerHTML = txt;         //<-- innerHTML
}

document.querySelector('#btn-search').addEventListener('click', e => {
  //Read query
  let q = document.querySelector('#search-query').value;
  console.log('raw query:', q);
  //Make search query html
  q = escapeHtml(q);
  console.log('html query:', q);
  //Perform search/highlight
  document.querySelectorAll('.search-in').forEach(node => {
    highlightSearch(node, q);
  });
});
```

```css
button {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<p class="search-in">abc &lt;div&gt;all is text &lt;/div&gt;</p>
<p class="search-in">a &lt;div> is not a &lt;/div>. but I can find 2 &lt;div></p>
<input type="search" id="search-query" value="<div>" />
<button id="btn-search">Search</button>
```

Comment: Tk, for your answer, but "div" just is example, it can be everything in `origin`
( const origin = "abc <div>all is text </div>"; // text input )
If I replace "div" with "<div>" your code will fail.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I responded to your question as it is, with the example you gave. If you have different cases, then you should edit your question to explicit your possible input/output. It's probably just a matter of changing the regex in there

Comment: thank you. I edit for my case, you can check it.

Comment: There you've got it

Comment: I've refactored the code to optimize it and make it clearer by breaking it into functions. I also changed the way I made the search Regexp `global` and `ignoreCase` as it didn't seem to work.

Comment: And removed all the RegExp complexity using method `String.replaceAll`. I'm not touching it again. Promised.

Comment: FYI, for highlighting text, you should use a `<mark>` element instead of `<span>`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't need to sanitize:

```js
const origin = document.querySelector("#inp").value;
const tmp = Object.assign( document.createElement("div"), {innerHTML: origin} );
tmp.querySelectorAll("div").forEach( el => {
  const left = `<span style="color:red">&lt;custom&gt;</span>`;
  const right = `<span style="color:red">&lt;/custom&gt;</span>`;
  const nwSpan = Object.assign( 
    document.createElement("span"),
    {innerHTML: `${left}${el.innerHTML}${right}`} );
  el.parentNode.replaceChild(nwSpan, el);
} );
console.log(tmp.innerHTML);
document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML = tmp.innerHTML;
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inp" value="abc <div>all is text </div>">

<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: This is not look like my case, can you check my case, It's hard for me, thank you