# How do I put a string containing double quotes into an HTML input element's value tag so that it properly renders on the page?

Tags: javascript, html

I've solved the problem but I wonder if there's a better way.

So, I have a string `'"Apple": 20'`. As you see, it contains double quotes. I want this string to render in a text input field.

Putting the string into the value attribute *as is* obviously wouldn't work:

`<input type=text value=""Apple": 20">` --> output: empty

I've tried escaping the quotes with a backslash but it doesn't work either:

`<input type=text value="\"Apple\": 20">` --> output: `\`

I figured, I need to replace the quotes with `&quot;`:

```js
let val = '"Apple": 20'
let re = /"/gi;
let modified_val = val.replace(re, '&quot;')

console.log(modified_val)
>>> &quot;Apple&quot;: 20
```

`<input type=text value="&quot;Apple&quot;: 20">` --> output: `"Apple": 20` (success)

But I wonder if there is a better way to achieve that? Better than replacing double quotes with `&quot;`.

EDIT:

I forgot to mention that I generate the HTML programmatically:

```js
element.innerHTML += `<input type=text value="${modified_val}">`
```

So, the value tag always uses double quotes.

Probably, there's a better way to add elements to a page, without hardcoding the quotes. But, so far, it seems that you always have to "manually" escape HTML characters when writing JavaScript strings to HTML. Like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234773/can-i-escape-html-special-chars-in-javascript).

Comment: Instead of js you could have done it with html only !  `<input type=text value='"Apple": 20'>

Comment: @Sanmeet I forgot to mention that I generate the HTML programmatically:

element.innerHTML += `\`<input type=text value="${modified_val}">\``
So, the value tag always uses double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't provide any html I assumed one !

**HTML**

```
<div id="div"></div>
```

**JS**

Using `document.createElement` method to first create an input element add some attributes and finally append it to main div.  (RECOMMENDED)

```
  const div = document.querySelector("#div")
  let value = '"Abc" : b';
  let input = document.createElement('input')
  const attributes = {
    type : "text",
    value : value
  }
  Object.entries(attributes).forEach( pair => input.setAttribute(pair[0], pair[1]))
  div.appendChild(input)
```

Using `innerHTML` without escaping string , the hack is just wrap the value string with the same  qoute ( double or single) as the value attribute qoute used !  ( NOT RECOMMENDED )

```
  const div = document.querySelector("#div")
  let value =  '"Abc" : b';
  div.innerHTML += `
    <input type="text"  value='${value}' />
  `
```

Comment: @m_ocean didn't knew about that innerHTML u should have mentioned it earlier and the html also with it ! ... Just tell me if this answer solves your problem ... It's without escaping characters 

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll rewrite my code soon and update you! 

Comment: @m_ocean Alrighty then  ! If any problem then summon me :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can also delimit it with single quotes

```
<input type="text" value='"Apple": 20'/>
```

The above will have the value as "Apple": 20 in the input box

Comment: I forgot to mention that I generate the HTML programmatically:

element.innerHTML += `\`<input type=text value="${modified_val}">\``
So, the value tag always uses double quotes.

Comment: @m_ocean That makes no difference in the answer. Write `<input type=text value='${modified_val}'>` then (notice the ' instead of "). You will have to escape `'` with.. i think it is `&apos;`. Using `&...;` is HTML standard for escaping, so you did that correctly.

Comment: It is going to be same..  element.innerHTML += `<input type="text"  value='"Apple": 20'/>`