# ReactJS: find html tags in a string and check if they are wrapped in backticks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got this huge string with commit messages containing HTML tags. I'm supposed to display it in the browser, but some of the tags haven't been escaped properly at commit creation time. Long story short, the browser tries to read them as normal tags instead of a string, and I get `Expected corresponding closing tag` error.

I'm looking for a way to go through all HTML tags in the string and add the missing backticks wherever needed.

Comment: see [stackoverflow.com/questions/6234773](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234773/can-i-escape-html-special-chars-in-javascript), or use a library like escape-html. But there seems to be something wrong because in [React](https://reactjs.org/) you should usually not deal with HTML (DOM) at all. React escapes HTML strings by default, unless you use [dangerouslysetinnerhtml](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

Answer (score 1):

Posting my solution in case someone finds it useful in the future.

The problem was, indeed, with the missing backticks. I ended up using this:

`` string.replace(/((?<!`)<[^>(?!`)]*>(?!`))/g, '`$1`') ``

to find all HTML tags that are not wrapped in backticks and wrap them in one.