# Vue filter should not consider html codes and tags in the count

Tags: javascript, vue.js, substring

Below is my vue filter applied to v-html,

```
    msg = "<p> don&#8217;t have comp from where </p>\n"

     <h2 v-html="this.$options.filters.limitText(msg)" ></h2>

     filters: {
      limitText: function (val) {
       if(val && (val.length > 28)) {
         return (val.substring(0, 28).replace(/\s\S*$/, '') + ' ...')
       }
      return val;
    
      }
    }
```

Below issues needs to be resolved in this filter :

1. It is considering `&#8217;` also as 7 characters in its character count for substring.  As it will be converted into just `'` it should be considered as only one character. Randomly I may get different codes in the text instead `&#8217;`.
2. It is considering the `p` tag,  `<p>` as three characters in its character count. This `<p>` tag needs to be skipped in the count. I may get different html tags in instead `p tag`, those tags should not be considered in character count for substring.

Comment: You need to escape those characters. Try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234773/can-i-escape-html-special-chars-in-javascript

Comment: I don't know much about vue, but if `.substring` is purely js function then it does not matter if it is v-html text, it will consider all string characters.