# How to sanitize user input string in nodejs, before injecting it in a template engine or say simple JS template string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, xss

I have webpages (basically business cards) whose titles are created based on user inputs.
I am planning to use simple JS template string for this purpose, instead of some template engine. (I am using express.js/node.js for this purpose)

```js
response.send(`
<html>

 <head>
  <title>${user_inputed_title_got_from_DB}</title>
  <meta property="og:title" content="${some_more_user_content}" />
 </head>

 <body>
  <script>
     window.location.href="/business-card/${user_input_number}";
  </script>
 </body>

</html>`)
```

How to avoid XSS injection from a malacious user?

Comment: https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For normal HTML tags, [this answer should suffice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6234804/5923139):

```js
function escapeHtml(unsafe)
{
    return unsafe
         .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
         .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
         .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
         .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
         .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
 }
```

However, your redirect in the script tag needs to be treated a bit more carefully. One common approach is to put the redirect in an attribute, which can be escaped with the above function:

```js
<script data-redir="/business-card/${escapeHtml(user_input_number)}">
    window.location.href = document.currentScript.dataset.redir;
</script>
```