# Update select box options within js.erb template - XSS safe and properly display text

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am rendering a `.js.erb` file within my rails app.  Within this file, I'm updating the options for a select box.

The most important thing is that I am doing this in a XSS Safe manner.  Given [the solution of this SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75451728/replace-options-from-ajax-response-in-xss-safe-manner), which references [OWASP DOM based XSS Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/DOM_based_XSS_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#guideline-3-use-documentcreateelement-elementsetattributevalue-elementappendchild-and-similar-to-build-dynamic-interfaces), I am updating the select box options the following way:

**Attempt 1**

```
// app/views/blogs/blogs_select_listing.js.erb

// remove all options
$('#blog_select_box').children().remove();

// iterate through @blogs collection, append each blog item as an option to select box
<% @blogs.each do |blog| %>
  var opt = document.createElement("option");
  opt.setAttribute("value", "<%= blog.id %>");
  opt.textContent = "<%= blog.name %>";
  $('#blog_select_box').append(opt);
<% end %>
```

- **Issue:** the display text of `blog.name` is being html encoded. So for example, the text of "Johnson & Johnson" is instead being displayed as: "Johnson `&amp;` Johnson". Other special characters like apostrophes will have the same display issue.

**Attempt 2**

I am aware of the rails method `html_safe`, so I tried that: I updated `"<%= blog.name %>";` to `"<%= blog.name.html_safe %>";`.

- **Issue**: When I test for XSS via having `blog.name` be something like `alert("Gotcha");`, it breaks:  The options are not updated at all.  Ultimately it seems that the issue is that using `html_safe` in this context, the app doesn't know how to handle double quotes.

**Atempt 3**

This *seems* to work. It updates the options, the display text works, and the option with display text `alert("gotcha");` simply displays as text and it doesn't execute as code:

```
// app/views/blogs/blogs_select_listing.js.erb

// remove all options
$('#blog_select_box').children().remove();

// iterate through @blogs collection, append each blog item as an option to select box
$('#blog_select_box')
.html("<%= j options_from_collection_for_select(@blogs, :id, :name) %>");
```

- **Issue**: I'm uncertain if this is safe. I am uncertain because I ran across [this article](https://dev.to/presidentbeef/why-escaping-javascript-is-dangerous-2pca) which expresses that `j`, which is an alias for `escape_javascript` is unsafe.

It is currently unclear how I can update select options from a `.js.erb` template which is both XSS safe and properly displays the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to give my understanding:

- To `Attempt 1`

Though you could [Unescape special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912501/unescape-html-entities-in-javascript), but it's not the Rails way.

- To `Attempt 2`

[html_safe](https://apidock.com/rails/String/html_safe) is not the method that can ensure you the string result is safe, but rather you clarify the string is safe, this way html tag within the string could be display as HTML, so it doesn't resolve XSS.

```rb
string = '<div>html with string</div>'
<%= string.html_safe %> # display as HTML
<%= string %> # display as string
```

- To `Attempt 3`

From [the article](https://dev.to/presidentbeef/why-escaping-javascript-is-dangerous-2pca), `escape_javascript` used within single or double quotes is safe.

```rb
# safe
'<%= j string %>' # or
"<%= j string %>"

# unsafe
<%= j string %>  # or
`<%= j string %>`
```

So `Attempt 3` is XSS safe, also it's the Rails way and is preferred.

And your code could be simplified:

```rb
# html() method will replace the original content, so you don't have to remove it first
$('#blog_select_box')
  .html("<%= j options_from_collection_for_select(@blogs, :id, :name) %>");
```