# Would using createElement instead of template literals prevent XSS?

Tags: javascript, xss

My messenger application is rendering each dialog using a template literal. This is causing unwanted behavior such as the `last_message` displaying links, images, or even executing scripts instead of just showing plain text. My messenger should only supports text messaging so users are unable to send images, voice attachments, etc.

Example incoming message:

```
var app = document.querySelector('body'); app.innerHTML = '<img src="x" onerror="alert(1)">';
```

```js
  renderDialogs: () => {
    const dialogList = document.getElementById('dialogsList');
    dialogList.textContent = '';

    const df = document.createDocumentFragment();

    dialogs.list.forEach(
      ({
        id,
        created,
        modified,
        username,
        other_user_id,
        unread_count,
        last_message,
      }) => {
        const btn = document.createElement('button');
        btn.classList =
          'list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item';
        btn.dataset.username = username;
        btn.dataset.userId = other_user_id;

        const btnContent = `
        <div class="d-flex flex-column gap-1 disable-pointer-events">
          <h5 class="mb-0 fs-6">${username}</h5>
          <p class="mb-0 text-muted preview-text">${last_message.text}</p>
          <p class="mb-0 dialog-unread"><span class="dialog-unread-count">${unread_count}</span> unread messages</p>
        </div>
      `;

        btn.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', btnContent);
        df.appendChild(btn);
      },
    );
    dialogList.appendChild(df);
  },
```

Would converting the following to use createElement prevent this mess? I used to use python bleach package to sanitize text in the backend, but it's now deprecated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace Options From AJAX Response in XSS Safe Manner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75451728/replace-options-from-ajax-response-in-xss-safe-manner)

Comment: createElement, on its own, would not prevent XSS attacks (assuming for example that `last_message.text` contains untrusted content). You'd still be injecting potentially unsafe content into the DOM, just via a differnet method.

Comment: Parsing it as html and adding it to the page is the unsafe part.  Delete from btnContent and after you insertAdjacentHtml you can `btn.querySelector('.preview-text').innerText = last_message.text` to safely set the text only without any html parsing.

Comment: "*Would converting the following to use createElement prevent this mess?*" - yes. But notice the problem is using `innerHTML`/`insertAdjacentHTML` with untrusted input, not the template literals themselves

Comment: @DanielBeck But if you never assign to `.innerHTML`, it won't parse any of the content as HTML or JavaScript, so there's no XSS.

Comment: "*I used to use python bleach package to sanitize text in the backend*" - you don't need to "sanitise" text, and you certainly shouldn't do it in the backend. You need to escape the text, at the point where you embed it into the HTML, regardless whether that happens on the frontend or on the backend.

Comment: Also, assigning to `.innerText` of an element will prevent it from being rendered as HTML.

Comment: *"if you never assign to .innerHTML, it won't parse any of the content as HTML or JavaScript, so there's no XSS"* If they just create a DOM element and don't inject any untrusted strings in it, yeah, that's safe of course. But I don't expect that's what they had in mind as a conversion of their existing code.