# jquery - append html doesn't append the empty String inside the div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am doing a `chat project` in `java`.

Using my `Server response` through `jquery-ajax` , I am creating an `html` and `append` the html to `div`.

My `jquery - html` alert `without empty string`-name(note the `id='user'` in the alert) will be ,

[image]

`after appending` this in the `chat area` ,

[image]

After `jquery-html` alert `with empty string`-name(note the `id='user'` in the alert) will be ,

[image]

`after appending` this in the `chat area` ,

[image]

My jquery for creating the HTML will be ,

```
function send(name , message , time){
    //name = $("#name").val();
    //message = $("#message").val();

    var user = "<div id='user' class='fontStyle'>"+name+"</div>";
    var msg = "<div id='msg'  class='fontStyle'>"+message+"</div>";
    var timeStamp = "<div id='time'  class='fontStyle'>"+time+"</div>";

    var row = "<div id='msgSet' >"+ user + msg + timeStamp +"</div>";

    alert(row);
    return row;

}
```

There is no empty string will be present in `chat area`.

Hope our stack members will help me.

Comment: Please post some code (current HTML/JS etc.)

Comment: Sorry added the code for creation of dynamic html..

Comment: You are aware that more than one whitespace gets condensed to one space character in HTML display under normal conditions …?

Comment: just use css min-width

Comment: Hmmm.But atleast I need one white space to split the name field and the message.

Comment: @KitePlayer http://stackoverflow.com/q/433493/1273830 @"split the .." don't. Use variables in common scope.

Comment: May be try and use `pre` tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can escape html your string so it keeps the white spaces. See details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251520/how-do-i-escape-some-html-in-javascript).

Or you can trim your message string (=remove spaces at the beginning and end of it) with such an instruction, and then manualy add the spaces (with the `&nbsp;` code inside a div, span, ...):

```
s.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
```