# Javascript to print a string which has xml contents

Tags: javascript, xml

I have a variable in javascript which has XML data.
When I try to print it, it prints only values of XML data and doesn't print XML tags.

I have this function:

```
function printxml(xmlData,requestTag) {
    var myWindow=window.open('');
    myWindow.document.write("<div id='hii'>+"xmlData+"<div>");
}
```

Where `xmldata` contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<book>
    <author>Sindhu</author>
    <BookName>BookName</BookName>
</book>
```

It prints only

```
SindhuBookName
```

Comment: [how to display xml in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/349250/how-to-display-xml-in-javascript) might help you

Comment: Have you checked the source? I think you'll find your XML there. The text you see on the screen are the two text nodes in your XML. If you want to show the tags, you've got to escape them.

Answer (score 3):

I am no Javascript expert, but I guess this is because your browser won't show you what it considers HTML tags. I think that you need to escape them, so that you can see the whole XML string.

Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/5251551/2466911